# Connect to MySQL from information provided by a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm stuck on this problem. I've been trying to use `http()` but doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's the form (It calls `ajax_request` when I submit, this works fine):

```
<form name='form-main'>
    <input id='host' type='text' placeholder='Host' />
    <input id='user' type='text' placeholder='Username' />
    <input id='db' type='text' placeholder='Database' />
    <input id='pass' type='password' placeholder='Password' />
</form>
```

and here's `ajax_request` part:

```
function ajax_request() {
    var host = document.getElementById('host').value;
    var user = document.getElementyById('user').value;
    var db = document.getElementById('db').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;

    var submitTo = 'DB.php';
    //alert(submitTo);
    http('POST', submitTo, ajax_response, 'Host='+host);
}
```

Here's `ajax_response`:

```
function ajax_response(data) {
    document.getElementById('web').value = data;
}
```

Finally, here's the PHP `DB.php` I'm trying to call:

```
<?php
    $Host = $_POST['Host'];
    $User = $_POST['User'];
    $DB = $_POST['DB'];
    $Pass = $_POST['Pass'];

    $iDB = new mysqli($Host, $User, $DB, $Pass);

    if($iDB->connect_errno) echo "no";
    else echo "yes";
?>
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to get the response either "yes" or "no" from the PHP and have it output on `ajax_response`

Answer (score 0):

Would you clearly and precisely describe the problem you're having?

At quick glance, I see you're performing an HTTP POST, but your PHP is looking for HTTP GET data. Changing your Javascript to perform an HTTP GET or your PHP to look at `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` may help or prevent additional problems.

PHP has the following variables: `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_REQUEST`. `$_GET` contains HTTP GET data. `$_POST` contains HTTP POST data. `$_REQUEST` contains both HTTP GET and POST data.

Comment: Sorry about that, still getting around PHP. The problem is actually on `ajax_request`. Nothing after `http()` gets called. I tried putting an `alert()` message before `http()` and one after `http()`, but I only get the first one.

Comment: @user1667191, I see. It looks like you will have to do some more debugging. First, I'm not too familiar with Javascript, but is http() a built-in function? Or did you write that? May I see where that's from? Second, would you show your browser console output when you try to call ajax_request()? The major browsers have developer tools, one of which is a Javascript console that should give you warning/error messages.

Comment: @user1667191, if http() is too troublesome, I would suggest the following. One, try using the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object in Javascript to do your GET/POST. Since you're new, this might be just as troublesome. Two, I really recommend importing a Javascript library, such as jQuery, and using their built-in [POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). This method helps with inter-browser compatibility and generally makes GET/POSTs much simpler.